# How to convert a varchar column to decimal?

Tags: sql-server

Here is sample data

-- Script to Create Table Schema

```
Create table myTable1(
    PREMIUM  varchar(50))
```

-- Script to Create Desired Data

```
Insert into myTable1 
values('25.90')
,('36.98')
,('67.89')
,('')
,('')
```

How do I convert varchar to decimal?  I have tried the below but getting error converting varchar to numeric

```
--script to create table where premium field is converted to decimal
select cast(premium as decimal(12,2)) as prem
into myTable2
from myTable1
```

Comment: You can not convert ''   (blank) to decimal.  You can do a check if its blank then convert.  Or dont use blanks use NULLS in your table.

Comment: Not related to your question, but why insert blank rows  `('')`  ? If you need empty values then use `null` instead of ''

Comment: What `decimal` value is `''` meant to be? 1? 0? Infinity? Something else? `''` isn't a valid number, as the error you were getting tells you. The *real* question is why are you storing numerical values as a `varchar` in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't convert character to Decimal. You can try this for ignoring blank space.

```
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN PREMIUM = ''
            THEN 0.00
        ELSE CAST(PREMIUM AS DECIMAL(12, 2))
        END AS PREM
INTO myTable2
FROM #myTable1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ignore invalid values and only want to insert valid decimals for that you can try like the following using `TRY_PARSE` .

```
select TRY_PARSE (premium as decimal(12,2)) as prem
into myTable2
from myTable1
where TRY_PARSE (premium as decimal(12,2)) IS NOT NULL
```

or like following using CTE

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
select TRY_PARSE (premium as decimal(12,2)) as prem
from myTable1
)
SELECT * into myTable2 FROM CTE
where prem IS NOT NULL
```

You can read more about TRY_PARSE [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-parse-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)